# Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated. Any alternative to send request before opening new page?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, deprecated

as the synchronous XMLHttpRequest is being deprecated, I'm wondering if there is some kind of alternative to simulate similar behaviour as non-blocking asynchronous XMLHttpRequests are not suitable for some cases.

I'm talking in particular about a case where I need to send a Post Request to the server, when an user clicks a hyperlink. Using PreventDefault is not an option here. With Synchronous XMLHttpRequest I can use an OnClick event, send the Request, and once it's done the browser continues it's default behaviour. Having the Request asynchonous, would have random results, as everything depends on how quick the new page loads so the Request can finish or not.

Is there any "modern" way how to freeze the browser's default behaviour till the Post Request finished?

Greetings and thanks.

Comment: Are you using any frameworks? Most make it easy to not load/show an element, and its children. in Angular you would do ng-show or ng-if="myCondition". Once this condition changes the element is shown. You can do the same thing in vanilla JS as well, though its not as easy.

Comment: I think that you maybe worrying a bit too much. In the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests it states: 'Note: Starting with Gecko 30.0 (Firefox 30.0 / Thunderbird 30.0 / SeaMonkey 2.27), synchronous requests on the main thread have been deprecated due to the negative effects to the user experience.' I take this to mean if the XHR request is within the onload event - but I could be wrong :-(

Comment: Or you can just use a normal for post and have the server redirect to the new page like we did in the old days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the callback:

```
window.location.href = "new url"
```

Comment: This should do the trick. Haven't thought about it. Sometimes the easiest way is the best one. Thanks.