# Javascript not working when I place before the body but works in header

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

for some odd reason my console is showing "[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience."

I know that is has something to do with how I am double loading my scripts but website only seems to function perfectly when I add both the scripts in the header and before the body.  When I try to add my scripts only in the body before the the closing tag my javascript completely stop working, im using mostly jquery for everything and my whole custom.js is wrapped in the $(document).ready() i dont understand

so heres how I load my script and and it works fine 
I add

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://js.pusher.com/3.0/pusher.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to the header

This is the script that I place before my closing body tag

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
```

so the deprecation messages disappears when i added it all to the closing body tag so im sure it has something to do with it maybe it has something to do with the order but i cant figure it out

Comment: you are loading jQuery in the body... try adding them like: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script><script src="https://js.pusher.com/3.0/pusher.min.js"></script><script src="bootstrap2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` in the header so they are available from the start or after you close `</body>`. if there are any script tags (with code), they should go after loading the scripts...

Comment: Loading the same script twice isn't good at all. And loading two different versions of jQuery either. But the error you have isn't related to that. It is related to an XMLHttpRequest (Ajax) occuring on load.

Comment: Whats the error message when the page stops working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated. Any alternative to send request before opening new page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36272753/synchronous-xmlhttprequest-on-the-main-thread-is-deprecated-any-alternative-to)

Comment: thanks diego that order works great that solved the double loading , also louys thanks for that article solved my depracation issue , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load jQuery library before loading jQuery-UI library since it is dependent on it. Even I had faced the same error when I started my career!